# Write Cookie Programmatically to Safari

Tags: cookies, safari, applescript

**Requirement:**

On a Mac, write a cookie in Safari to a particular domain on startup.

So far the options I can think of are.

**1. Safari's cookie file**

On startup, write the cookie directly to Safari's binary file located in `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies`. However, I don't know if this is possible and cannot find any documentation on it. I'm reluctant to try this incase the file has a checksum against it.

**2. Get Safari to set it**

On startup, using AppleScript, launch Safari silently/hidden and navigate to a site which sets the cookie.

- Are there any other ways I could do this?
- How can I lauch Safari silently using AppleScript and navigate to a url?
- How can I could programmatically register said AppleScript to
  launch on startup.

I'm predominantly a c# windows developer so I'm a little out of my comfort zone here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cookies are shared globally on OS X, you can use this little bit of AppleScript/ObjC to add cookies from a website by loading the website in an invisible WebView, which just gets released once the loading is done, and the cookies have been saved. Note that you have to create a "Cocoa-AppleScript Applet" from the "New from Template" menu in the File menu of Script Editor.

```
display alert set_cookies_for_URL("http://www.apple.com")
(* AppleScript's handlers all seem to become unusable after importing frameworks.
 * To compensate, I'm relegating AppleScript/ObjC calls to the end of the file
 *)
use framework "WebKit"

on set_cookies_for_URL(URL)
    set web_view to current application's WebView's alloc()'s initWithFrame:(current application's NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 500)) frameName:"tempFrame" groupName:"tempGroup"
    set web_view's mainFrameURL to URL
    #delay to avoid release
    repeat while ((web_view's isLoading) as boolean) is true
        delay 1
    end repeat
    return "done"
end set_cookies_for_URL
```

Comment: I added this to a launch agent and it works really well. I modified it so it doesn't show the message and just ends silently however it shows the app icon in the dock briefly. Is there anyway to suppress this?

Comment: Sure. Follow the steps at this URL: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/easy_mac_hacks_run_os_x_applications_without_their_dock_icon

Comment: That worked - Seriously dude, if you're ever in Newcastle UK the beers are on me :D

Comment: @heymega Sounds good! I definitely plan to head there some day. :)

Comment: cookies aren't shared globally. safari puts them in `~/Library/Cookies`