# JWT token cookie not storing on Safari IOS or Mac

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I've developed this MERN app and deployed it on Render.com with my frontend being Static Site and backend Web Static. It is also has a domain using GoDaddy. Now, I have a login api where I store a jwt token on a cookie. The cookie is generating or storing on websites like chrome, edge, opera, etc but NOT in Safari browser (IOS, MAC). Unless I go to Safari > Preferences > Privacy and uncheck Prevent cross-site tracking then it would work but it is not applicable and user-friendly.

In my Axios POST login, this is how I setup my jwt token cookie:

```
 const token = jwt.sign(
    { email: user.email, role: user.role, userID: user._id },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    }
  );

  res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: "xxx-api.onrender.com",
    secure: true, // Set to true if your application is served over HTTPS
    sameSite: "none",
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 86400000,
  });
```

I've also done research and tried doing **sameSite: "lax"** or **sameSite: "strict"** but it says something about the cookie is not *top-level nagivation*. What would be the fix here? Thank you!

Comment: It’s a security matter. You might want to look into [Manage cookies and website data on Safari](https://help.apple.com/safari/mac/8.0/en.lproj/sfri11471.html)

Answer (score 0):

It’s a security matter. By default, Safari accepts cookies and website data only from websites you visit.

If a user blocks cookies from your website, you cannot do anything about it.

You might want to look into [Manage cookies and website data on Safari. <sup>[apple]</sup>](https://help.apple.com/safari/mac/8.0/en.lproj/sfri11471.html)

Comment: What could be a work around here? I don't want the user to turn off their cross-site tracking since it would be a risk on their side. Is it possible to make a JWT token a first-party cookie instead of a third-party?

Comment: Does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118694/16770846)?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured what's wrong! onrender.com is a public suffix. The way I've fixed it is setting my Static Site and Web Service as a subdomain for GoDaddy domain.
My custom domain settings are Static site ([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)) and Web Service (service.mydomain.com).

Then on GoDaddy, I've add A and CNAME for Static site and CNAME only for Web Service.